# Can I use log of two variables and also the ratio of the two variables in linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-transformation, linear-model

I am working on a linear regression model to predict revenue (of a city) from a marketing campaign. The independent variables are spend, population of city etc.
[Please note for the model, I only care about the predictions, not much if the coefficients, model are interpretable ]

As independent variables, can I use log(spend), log(population), spend / population ?  One logical reason for using the ratio variable is that practically (in our case) spend is allocated based on population by tiers of cities. Also spend/population gives a sense of marketing spend per population.

1. Will there be any issues in using all the three variables in the model, from model point of view. Like is spend/population a perfect linear combination of log(spend) and log(population) ? (and the determinant in the process of coming up with coefficients doesn't exist. )
2. Will it make sense from interpretation point of view, having all 3 in the model ?

I have  taken a look at this. and wanted to check the case of log variables and if ratio is considered as linear combination of the the log variables.
[Ratio of explanatory variables in multiple regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112878/ratio-of-explanatory-variables-in-multiple-regression)

3. Will it make sense to predict log(Revenue) instead of revenue. What are cons and pros of predicting log(Revenue) instead of revenue. One pro is log(Revenue) constraints the range and helps the model learn better (Correct me if wrong)
4. Is it against the assumptions of the linear regression, to include spend/population variable because it will be highly correlated to the other variables ?

Comment: A ratio is not generally a linear combination of the logarithms (except in very special cases where the values of the two variables are limited to special combinations.)  What do you mean in (1) that the "determinant doesn't exist"?

Comment: @whuber  I mean if it (1 var) is a perfect linear combination of other variables, the determinant in the computation of the coefficient matrix (my idea about the process of coefficient matrix computation). I was of the idea that ratio is lot linear combination of the logarithms of vars but my friend says it is, can you please provide any logic why it is not (I assume a/b cannot be linearly expressed in log(a) + log(b) or log(ab), right ?)

Comment: I suspect your friend is confused by the fact that $\log(a/b) = \log(a) - \log(b)$.

Comment: Suppose there existed coefficients $x$ and $y$ for which $a/b=x\log(a)+y\log(b)$ for various values of $a,b.$  Suppose the include three distinct values of $(a,b),$ written $(a_i,b_i).$ Then $a_i/b_i=x\log(a_i)+y\log(b_i)$ are three distinct linear restrictions on $(x,y).$ Unless these restrictions are redundant, there cannot be any solution.